# Use ctypes to import dll function

Tags: python, vb6, ctypes, vb6-migration

I need to do a porting of a VB6 program to python.
This program, communicate with a Bentel Kyo anti-theft control unit using a DLL.
In VB6 i declare the function in this way:

```
Public Declare Function PanelConnection Lib "C:\SupervisioneCasa\BisKyoUnit.dll" (ByVal Comando As Long, ByVal Porta As Byte, tentativi, ByRef pin As Byte, ByVal LenPin As Byte, ByRef presult As Byte) As Byte
```

And calling the function in this way:

```
ExitCode = PanelConnection(&H302, 1, 1, 0, 0, Buffer(0))
```

I try to translate the VB6 code in python in this way:

```
import ctypes

hllDll = ctypes.WinDLL ("c:\\Appoggio\\BisKyoUnit.dll")

array_type = ctypes.c_byte * 255
Buffer = array_type()

hllApiProto = ctypes.WINFUNCTYPE (
    ctypes.c_byte,      # Return type.
    ctypes.c_long,   # Parameters 1 ...
    ctypes.c_byte,
    ctypes.c_int,
    ctypes.c_byte,
    ctypes.c_byte,
    ctypes.c_byte)   # ... thru 6.
hllApiParams = (1, "p1", 0), (1, "p2", 0), (1, "p3",0), (1, "p4",0), (1, "p5",0), (1, "p6",0),

hllApi = hllApiProto (("PanelConnection", hllDll), hllApiParams)

p1 = ctypes.c_long (302)
p2 = ctypes.c_byte (1)
p3 = ctypes.c_int (1)
p4 = ctypes.c_byte (0)
p5 = ctypes.c_byte (0)
p6 = ctypes.c_byte (Buffer)
hllApi (p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6)
```

but when i try to runtime the py, I obtain this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "y:\Downloads\Python\Bentel.py", line 28, in <module>
    p6 = ctypes.c_byte (Buffer)
TypeError: an integer is required
```

Where am I wrong? Anyone can help me?
Thanks.

Yuri

Comment: I don't see a datatype for  `tentativi` in your VB6 declare statement?

Comment: tentativi is an integer value. It is the number of attempts if communication fail.

Comment: `ByRef` values are pointers, and need `POINTER(c_byte)`.  Do you have the C prototype or documentation for API you are trying to call?

Comment: You can download the API documentation here: http://www.bentelsecurity.com/CMS/download.php?t=1&id=865

Answer (score 0):

I try to re-write the function in this way:

```
import ctypes

dll = ctypes.windll.LoadLibrary("c:\\Appoggio\\BisKyoUnit.dll")

py_swe_calc_ut = dll.PanelConnection
py_swe_calc_ut.argtypes = [ctypes.c_long, ctypes.c_byte, ctypes.c_int, ctypes.c_byte, ctypes.c_byte, ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_byte*255)]
py_swe_calc_ut.restype = None

returnarray = (ctypes.c_byte * 255)()

ExitCode = py_swe_calc_ut(302, 1, 1, 0, 0, returnarray)
```

This way, no error is returned. But in practice the call doesn't work. Nothing is returned in `returnarray`.
Any help?
Thank you.